# Visual Basic - Raise Event

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on an assignment that wants me to raise and event alert. Details are below.

Do exercises 4.1 to 4.3 at the end of chapter 4 as shown below. You will need to submit two versions of your code, one with static event handler, and the other with dynamic event handling:

4.1 Using the Car code class of chapter 3 exercises, add code that declares and raises an event named LowGas. This event is raised when the gas level reaches 5 or lower.

4.2 On the form side, add code so that when the LowGas event is raised, the event is handled by asking the user to pump gas using static event handling.

4.3 To practice Dynamic event handling, implement the handling of the LowGas event using dynamic event handling. Ensure that you remove the handler properly.

I've tried reading over the textbook numerous of times, but I still feel lost on the assignment.

```
Public Class Car
    'Properties of car
    Private VINNumber As Integer
    Private mGasLevel As Double
    Private mMileage As Double
    Private mMPG As Double
    Event gasAlert()
    Private messageLog As String

    Public ReadOnly Property GasLevel() As Double
        Get
            Return mGasLevel
    End Get
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property MPG() As Double
    Get
        Return mMPG
    End Get
End Property

Public Property Mileage() As Double
    Get
        Return mMileage
    End Get
    Set(value As Double)
        mMileage = value
    End Set
End Property

'method pump-gas to pump gas into the car
Public Sub PumpGas(gallons As Double)
    mGasLevel = mGasLevel + gallons
    'TextBox3.Text = c.GasLevel

End Sub

'method drive to drive the car
Public Sub Drive(driven As Double)

    Dim drive As Double
    Dim ableToDrive As Double
    messageLog = ""

    If driven > 0 Then
        drive = driven
        ableToDrive = (GasLevel * MPG)

        If drive > ableToDrive Then
            messageLog = "Gas Level is too low it has only" & Format(GasLevel, "0.#") & " gallons in the tank, you wil be able" & vbNewLine & "to drive" & Format(ableToDrive, "0.#") & " miles. Please Pump Gas"
            mMileage = Mileage + drive
            mGasLevel = GasLevel - (drive / MPG)
        Else
            mMileage = Mileage + ableToDrive
            mGasLevel = GasLevel - (ableToDrive / MPG)
        End If

        If mGasLevel <= 5 Then
            messageLog = ""
            RaiseEvent gasAlert()
        End If

    End If
End Sub

'constructor to create class
Public Sub New(ByVal v As Integer, ByVal g As Double, ByVal m As Double, ByVal mp As Double)
    VINNumber = v
    mGasLevel = g
    mMileage = m
    mMPG = mp
End Sub

End Class

Public Class Form1

'initial form level parameters
Dim c As Car
Dim WithEvents eventCar As Car
Dim messageLog As String
Dim isCarCreated As Boolean

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    Label5.Visible = False
End Sub

'method to create a new car
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox1.Text <> String.Empty And TextBox2.Text <> String.Empty And TextBox3.Text <> String.Empty And TextBox4.Text <> String.Empty Then
        c = New Car(Convert.ToInt64(TextBox1.Text), Convert.ToDouble(TextBox3.Text), Convert.ToDouble(TextBox2.Text), Convert.ToDouble(TextBox4.Text))
        Label5.Visible = True
        Label5.Text = "New Car Created!!"
        isCarCreated = True
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Make sure everything is filled out first.", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

    End If

End Sub

'click method to call pump gas method and accept the gallons of gas
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim gallons As Double
    If c IsNot Nothing Then

        gallons = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox6.Text)
        c.PumpGas(gallons)
        TextBox3.Text = c.GasLevel
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Create a car first before pumping gas.", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

    End If
End Sub

'click method to call Drive method to drive the car
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim driven As Double

    If c IsNot Nothing Then
        driven = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox5.Text)

        TextBox2.Text = c.Mileage
        TextBox3.Text = c.GasLevel
        AddHandler c.gasAlert, AddressOf gasAlertNotificationDynamic
        c.Drive(driven)
        RemoveHandler c.gasAlert, AddressOf gasAlertNotificationDynamic
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Create a car first before driving.", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnRemoveCar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRemoveCar.Click
    If c IsNot Nothing Then
        c = Nothing
        Label5.Visible = False
        TextBox1.Text = String.Empty
        TextBox2.Text = String.Empty
        TextBox3.Text = String.Empty
        TextBox4.Text = String.Empty
        TextBox5.Text = String.Empty
        TextBox6.Text = String.Empty
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("There are no cars created.", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

    End If
End Sub
Sub gasAlertNotificationStatic() Handles eventCar.gasAlert
    MessageBox.Show("Only " & Format(c.GasLevel, "#.#") & " gallons left.", "Gas Alert _ static", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
End Sub

Sub gasAlertNotificationDynamic()
    MessageBox.Show("Only " & Format(c.GasLevel, "#.#") & " gallons left.", "Gas Alert _ dynamic", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
End Sub
End Class
```

When I run the application, create a car, and try to drive the car, the alert gets raised when it should only happen when I'm at 5 gallons or less.

Comment: Hi, please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named [What to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the [StackOverflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It seems that your issue is in the `Public Sub Drive(driven As Double)` method. To get to the `RaiseEvent gasAlert()` call code needs to get to the `If mGasLevel <= 5 Then`. That means that the `If driven > 0 Then` succeeded. I'd put a breakpoint on that line an watch what happens as you step through each line. You haven't given us your starting conditions so that's the best I can say as to what is going on for you.

Comment: What has you lost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your issue is in the `Public Sub Drive(driven As Double)` method. To get to the `RaiseEvent gasAlert()` call code needs to get to the `If mGasLevel <= 5 Then`. That means that the `If driven > 0 Then` succeeded. I'd put a breakpoint on that line an watch what happens as you step through each line. You haven't given us your starting conditions so that's the best I can say as to what is going on for you.

Just to give you a bit more of a helping hand I've refactored your code. I hope this is helpful:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private WithEvents _car As Car

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.UpdateUI(String.Empty)
    End Sub

    Private Function ParseNullableInteger(text As String) As Integer?
        Dim result As Integer? = Nothing
        Dim x As Integer
        If (Integer.TryParse(text, x)) Then
            result = x
        End If
        Return result
    End Function

    Private Function ParseNullableDouble(text As String) As Double?
        Dim result As Double? = Nothing
        Dim x As Double
        If (Double.TryParse(text, x)) Then
            result = x
        End If
        Return result
    End Function

    Private Sub ButtonCreateCar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonCreateCar.Click
        Dim vinNumber = ParseNullableInteger(TextBoxVinNumber.Text)
        Dim gasLevel = ParseNullableDouble(TextBoxGasLevel.Text)
        Dim mpg = ParseNullableDouble(TextBoxMpg.Text)
        If vinNumber.HasValue AndAlso gasLevel.HasValue AndAlso mpg.HasValue Then
            _car = New Car(vinNumber.Value, gasLevel.Value, mpg.Value)
            UpdateUI("New Car Created!!")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Make sure everything is filled out first.", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonPumpGas_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonPumpGas.Click
        If _car IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim gallons = ParseNullableDouble(TextBoxGallons.Text)
            If gallons.HasValue Then
                _car.PumpGas(gallons)
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Enter gallons correctly.", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End If
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Create a car first before pumping gas.", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonDrive_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonDrive.Click
        If _car IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim driven = ParseNullableDouble(TextBoxDriven.Text)
            If driven.HasValue Then
                AddHandler _car.LowGas, AddressOf LowGasHandlerDynamic
                _car.Drive(driven)
                RemoveHandler _car.LowGas, AddressOf LowGasHandlerDynamic
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Enter driven correctly.", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End If
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Create a car first before driving.", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonRemoveCar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonRemoveCar.Click
        If _car IsNot Nothing Then
            _car = Nothing
            Me.UpdateUI(String.Empty)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("There are no cars created.", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub UpdateUI(message As String)
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(message) Then
            Me.LabelMessage.Visible = True
            Me.LabelMessage.Text = message
        Else
            Me.LabelMessage.Visible = False
        End If
        Me.TextBoxVinNumber.Enabled = _car Is Nothing
        Me.TextBoxMpg.Enabled = _car Is Nothing
        Me.TextBoxGasLevel.Enabled = _car Is Nothing
        Me.TextBoxDriven.Enabled = _car IsNot Nothing
        Me.TextBoxGallons.Enabled = _car IsNot Nothing
        If _car IsNot Nothing Then
            Me.TextBoxMileage.Text = _car.Mileage
            Me.TextBoxGasLevel.Text = _car.GasLevel
        Else
            Me.TextBoxVinNumber.Text = String.Empty
            Me.TextBoxMileage.Text = String.Empty
            Me.TextBoxGasLevel.Text = String.Empty
            Me.TextBoxMpg.Text = String.Empty
            Me.TextBoxDriven.Text = String.Empty
            Me.TextBoxGallons.Text = String.Empty
        End If
        Me.TextBoxMileage.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub CarDrivenOrPumped(sender As Object, args As EventArgs) Handles _car.CarDriven, _car.CarPumped
        Me.UpdateUI(String.Empty)
    End Sub

    Private Sub LowGasHandlerStatic(sender As Object, args As EventArgs) Handles _car.LowGas
        MessageBox.Show("Only " & Format(_car.GasLevel, "0.0") & " gallons left.", "Gas Alert _ static", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    End Sub

    Private Sub LowGasHandlerDynamic(sender As Object, args As EventArgs)
        MessageBox.Show("Only " & Format(_car.GasLevel, "0.0") & " gallons left.", "Gas Alert _ dynamic", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Car
    Public Event LowGas As EventHandler
    Public Event CarDriven As EventHandler
    Public Event CarPumped As EventHandler

    Public Sub New(ByVal vinNumber As Integer, ByVal gasLevel As Double, ByVal mpg As Double)
        Me.VinNumber = vinNumber
        Me.GasLevel = gasLevel
        Me.Mpg = mpg
    End Sub

    Private _gasLevel As Double = 0.0

    Public Property GasLevel() As Double
        Get
            Return _gasLevel
        End Get
        Private Set(value As Double)
            _gasLevel = value
            If _gasLevel <= 5 Then
                RaiseEvent LowGas(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property VinNumber() As Double
    Public ReadOnly Property Mpg() As Double
    Public ReadOnly Property Mileage() As Double
        Get
            Return Me.Mpg * Me.GasLevel
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub PumpGas(gallons As Double)
        Me.GasLevel += gallons
        RaiseEvent CarPumped(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Drive(driven As Double)
        Dim actually = Math.Min(driven, Me.Mileage)
        If actually > 0 Then
            Me.GasLevel -= actually / Me.Mpg
            RaiseEvent CarDriven(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

---

Or even this more slightly streamlined version of `Form1`:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private WithEvents _car As Car

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.UpdateUI(String.Empty)
    End Sub

    Private Function ParseNullableInteger(text As String) As Integer?
        Dim result As Integer? = Nothing
        Dim x As Integer
        If (Integer.TryParse(text, x)) Then
            result = x
        End If
        Return result
    End Function

    Private Function ParseNullableDouble(text As String) As Double?
        Dim result As Double? = Nothing
        Dim x As Double
        If (Double.TryParse(text, x)) Then
            result = x
        End If
        Return result
    End Function

    Private Sub ButtonCreateCar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonCreateCar.Click
        Dim vinNumber = ParseNullableInteger(TextBoxVinNumber.Text)
        Dim gasLevel = ParseNullableDouble(TextBoxGasLevel.Text)
        Dim mpg = ParseNullableDouble(TextBoxMpg.Text)
        If vinNumber.HasValue AndAlso gasLevel.HasValue AndAlso mpg.HasValue Then
            _car = New Car(vinNumber.Value, gasLevel.Value, mpg.Value)
            UpdateUI("New Car Created!!")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Make sure everything is filled out first.", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonPumpGas_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonPumpGas.Click
        Dim gallons = ParseNullableDouble(TextBoxGallons.Text)
        If gallons.HasValue Then
            _car.PumpGas(gallons)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Enter gallons correctly.", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonDrive_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonDrive.Click
        Dim driven = ParseNullableDouble(TextBoxDriven.Text)
        If driven.HasValue Then
            AddHandler _car.LowGas, AddressOf LowGasHandlerDynamic
            _car.Drive(driven)
            RemoveHandler _car.LowGas, AddressOf LowGasHandlerDynamic
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Enter driven correctly.", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonRemoveCar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonRemoveCar.Click
        _car = Nothing
        Me.UpdateUI(String.Empty)
    End Sub

    Private Sub UpdateUI(message As String)
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(message) Then
            Me.LabelMessage.Visible = True
            Me.LabelMessage.Text = message
        Else
            Me.LabelMessage.Visible = False
        End If
        Me.UpdateUI()
    End Sub

    Private Sub UpdateUI()
        Me.ButtonCreateCar.Enabled = _car Is Nothing
        Me.ButtonDrive.Enabled = _car IsNot Nothing
        Me.ButtonPumpGas.Enabled = _car IsNot Nothing
        Me.ButtonRemoveCar.Enabled = _car IsNot Nothing
        Me.TextBoxVinNumber.Enabled = _car Is Nothing
        Me.TextBoxMpg.Enabled = _car Is Nothing
        Me.TextBoxGasLevel.Enabled = _car Is Nothing
        Me.TextBoxDriven.Enabled = _car IsNot Nothing
        Me.TextBoxGallons.Enabled = _car IsNot Nothing
        If _car IsNot Nothing Then
            Me.TextBoxMileage.Text = _car.Mileage
            Me.TextBoxGasLevel.Text = _car.GasLevel
        Else
            Me.TextBoxVinNumber.Text = String.Empty
            Me.TextBoxMileage.Text = String.Empty
            Me.TextBoxGasLevel.Text = String.Empty
            Me.TextBoxMpg.Text = String.Empty
            Me.TextBoxDriven.Text = String.Empty
            Me.TextBoxGallons.Text = String.Empty
        End If
        Me.TextBoxMileage.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub CarDrivenOrPumped(sender As Object, args As EventArgs) Handles _car.CarDriven, _car.CarPumped
        Me.UpdateUI()
    End Sub

    Private Sub LowGasHandlerStatic(sender As Object, args As EventArgs) Handles _car.LowGas
        MessageBox.Show("Only " & Format(_car.GasLevel, "0.0") & " gallons left.", "Gas Alert _ static", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    End Sub

    Private Sub LowGasHandlerDynamic(sender As Object, args As EventArgs)
        MessageBox.Show("Only " & Format(_car.GasLevel, "0.0") & " gallons left.", "Gas Alert _ dynamic", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your code definitely helped me understand the concept. I compared it with my messy code and made the necessary adjustments. I appreciate your effort on this. Thank you once again.